# How can I install UI Kitten on Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ui-kitten

I'm trying to use UI Kitten on my project but can't figure out how to install UI Kitten on Expo.

```
expo install @ui-kitten/eva-icons @eva-design/eva @ui-kitten/components react-native-svg
```

Error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: react-native-svg@12.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-svg
npm ERR!   react-native-svg@"12.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native-svg@"^9.13.6" from @ui-kitten/components@5.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@ui-kitten/components
npm ERR!   @ui-kitten/components@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @ui-kitten/components@"5.1.0" from @ui-kitten/eva-icons@5.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ui-kitten/eva-icons
npm ERR!     @ui-kitten/eva-icons@"*" from the root project
```

Answer (score 0):

In error it is clearly shown that `react-native-svg@"^9.13.6"` kitten UI is using the above version and your project is using `12.1.0` for using kitten UI you need to use `react-native-svg@"^9.13.6"`  version.

Comment: I get same error even using `expo install @ui-kitten/eva-icons @eva-design/eva @ui-kitten/components react-native-svg@9.13.6`

Answer (score 0):

It's NPM 7 responsible for it.
Running this should fix it:

```
npm install -g npm@6
```